# Self-Executing C program or Bash file

Tags: c, bash, startup

I am writing a program/script that should check what services are running on a computer every hour.  Is there a way to automatically launch this program every hour?  I could manually launch it but that would defeat the purpose of the script.  Sorry for the ambiguity of the question.  I will update it as I get responses.

EDIT: Linux local desktops and Windows remote desktops.  Cron and scheduler seem to be the tools needed to launch the program.  How do I automatically add my script to them?  Manually adding the script to each box would be tedious.

Comment: What platform are you on? `cron`?

Comment: It will be for both Windows and Linux.

Comment: `cron` is what you want.  `Scheduler` for windows.  Unfortunately, there's not a good portable solution..except just running in the background, which isn't really preferable except in the right circumstances.

Comment: If you have ssh access or similar, you could run the job on one host, and ssh to each of the computers you monitor within that job. This is beginning to sound like Nagios or Munin; perhaps you are really looking for a monitoring framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more about your OS than language.

You could make an app that sleeps for 60 mins then does a check (put it in a loop and you're done), but on unix systems you would be better of using cron. On Windows it's called the scheduler and has APIs to access it.

Comment: Assuming I am understanding my brief read on cron, I will have to manually add the script to the crontab.  This script is going to be used across company, so close to 100 computers.  Is there a way to have the script move itself accordingly after executing once?

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific about what you are trying to solve and on what platforms. Sounds like you have linux desktops and want to check certain tools are running on them once per hour?

Comment: I have both Linux and Windows desktops.  The Windows desktops are remote.  But yes, I would like to know what is running once per hour.  I am fairly confident I can write the script that will check in either Bash or C, I just need to know how to make it check every hour.  It would be rather annoying going to every box and manually editing the crontab files.  I have been reading about them since you mentioned them and they seem easy enough.  I would just like to avoid the tedious work of editing all of them.